# Nesting two Javascript events

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

I'm trying to call a function through an `eventlistener` in Javascript, and within the function I have invoked another `eventlistener`. However on doing this, my second listener is completely ignored. Is there any condition which I need to follow to make this work?

```
    document.getElementById("my_canvas").addEventListener("mouseenter", this.getAttention); //first event listener 

getAttention: function(e){
    document.addEventListener("onclick", function(){ console.log("Hello World!"); });
```

Here the "Hello World" is not consoled.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is ignored because the first parameter expects event string to be without "on", try this

`document.addEventListener("click", function(){ console.log("Hello World!"); });`

Answer (score 1):

When invoking the addEventListener method you pass in the name of the event as the first argument. The name of the click event is 'click'.

```
document.addEventListener('click', myFunc);
```

The syntax for registering a click event handler as a HTML attribute is onclick

```
<button onclick="myFunc"></button>
```